# Renomear aplicação no Django Admin

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.7, django-admin

Boa noite galera, estou tentando renomear a aplicação no django admin de acordo a documentação, mas acabou nao surtindo efeito, acho que estou fazendo algo de errado, o código esta da seguinte forma:

**controledebolsistas/ apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ControledebolsistasConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'controledebolsistas'
    verbose_name = "Controle de Bolsistas"
```

**_init__.py**

```
default_app_config = 'controledebolsistas.apps.ControledebolsistasConfig'
```

Ele apresenta um erro **'ImportError: No module named 'controledebolsistas'**, acho que estou fazendo algo de errado, eu preciso de algum **import** nesses arquivos?? Sou novo com django e quem puder me ajudar eu agradeço!!
'

Comment: Coloque o app no INSTALLED_APPS no arquivo settings.py. Já fez?

Comment: Então a aplicação já criada está no INSTALLED_APPS como 'gestaobolsistas.controledebolsistas', e segundo a documentação teria que acrescentar 'controledebolsistas.apps.ControledebolsistasAppConfig'

Comment: Mas tbm não funcionou

Comment: ele continuando mostrando que não existe módulo com o nome de 'controledebolsistas'

Comment: Coloque aqui o link da documentação que você acessou.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/#for-application-users

Comment: O arquivo está __init__.py com duplo sublinhado ou você escreveu errado? Ali encima só há um no começo.

Comment: eu escrevi daquele jeito porque quando fui digitar na pergunta não estava aceitando

Comment: Tenta ver se dá certo colocando o nome do projeto antes do nome do app em default_app_config.

Comment: Não deu certo, acho que ele não esta reconhecendo o _init_.py

Comment: Faz um teste colocando só 'controledebolsistas' no INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: @WalkyrRosa como é que está a estrutura dos diretórios do seu projeto?

Comment: Sistema/gestaobolsistas/controledebolsistas, está assim! gestaobolsistas é projeto criado e controle de bolsistas é a aplicação

Comment: Já tentou colocar `'gestaobolsitas.controledebolsistas.apps.ControledebolsistasConfig'`?

Answer (score 0):

Para incluir a aplicação no projeto, voce percisa adicionar a referência à classe de configuração da aplicação na definição do INSTALLED_APPS. A classe ControledebolsistasConfig está no arquivo :file: 'controledebolsistas/apps.py', certo? Então seu caminho pontuado é 'Controledebolsistas.apps.ControledebolsistasConfig'. Edite o arquivo settings.py e adicione aquele caminho com notação de ponto. A definição do INSTALLED_APPS. Ficará parecido com isto:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'Controledebolsistas.apps.ControledebolsistasConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Coloque a sua aplicação dentro do INSTALLED_APPS, o resto está correto!!

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'controledebolsistas',
]
```